# Autoscroll div overflow content

Tags: jquery, scroll, overflow, hidden

I have one div 800px by 150px, and then some other divs inside that.  The outer one have overflow hidden so you can't see what goes beyond the outer div.  But i want users to be able to scroll through it horizontally to see more content.  Also, I want to have a jquery script running where if they're not scrolling through it, it will automatically scroll.
Something like this:

```
<div id="mask" style="width: 800px; height: 150px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
<div id="inside-content"><img src="images/thing.jpg"></div>
<div id="inside-content"><img src="images/thing.jpg"></div>
<div id="inside-content"><img src="images/thing.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on how to do this are welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's the HTML/CSS working: http://jsfiddle.net/KDhPX/ - for the jQuery you'll have to post what you've tried and exactly which part you're having problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use overflow-x and overflow-y to provide different scroll/hide-behaviour instead of the shorthand overflow CSS-property and float your inside-content. (And don't use multiple IDs anywhere in your document, but classes instead).

[See JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AK6Jy/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="mask">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="inside-content">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/150/city" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="inside-content">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/150/sport" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="inside-content">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/150/people" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mask {
    width: 800px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.inner {
    width: 2400px; /* 3 times mask */
}

.inside-content {
    float: left;
}
```